# Django / duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: python, django, view, django-users

I try to extend django auth user model with OneToOneField but couldn't solve this problem.

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_profile_user_id_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(67) already exists.

I look through this issue , some people say the db out of sync.

***views.py***

```
def create_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        registration = user_form.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = registration
        profile.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request, 'registration/registration.html', 
                                            {'user_form': user_form, 
                                            'profile_form': profile_form})
```

***models.py***

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/assets",
                               default="blog/assets/people-photo.jpg",
                               null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

***forms.py***

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password')
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user_image', 'birth_date',)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your most trouble is: you try to create profile double time:
by signal and by form.
May be you can just remove the signal.

Or try to use `get_or_create` instead of simple `create` as i can see it does not break your logic

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and override save form:

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
    registration = user_form.save()
    # Set user password
    registration.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=registration.profile)
    if profileis_valid():
        profile.save()
```

Comment: thank you so much. could you give me any tip on django for learning ? ,

Comment: glad to help you, look here[django info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info)

Comment: I figured out right now. I can create users but cant login with it. can you see the problem on my logic ?. I checked with shell_plus the user passwords created with form got no password hash.

Comment: added `set_password`