# duplicate key value violates unique constraint error in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a model named package in an app named exam.
I use Django rest framework and have the following View:

```
class PackageListCreaet(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminAndReadOnlyForStaff,)

    @method_decorator(rest_error_decorator(logger))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and the following serializer:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ('pk','name','price','exams','active')
```

when I try creating a new package from Django admin it works just fine.
But when I try creating a new package using the API above it throws the following error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"exam_package_pkey\"\nDETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists
```

And it's worth mentioning that although I get this error the object gets created.(and so the "(id)=(1) number changes each time".)

I looked around a bit to find a solution and realized the problem is that the id field of exam_package table is out of sync. I tried syncing it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286480/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-in-django) and it didn't work.
Then I tried removing all records (which happened with no error) and setting the primary key to 1 [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819292/reset-postgresql-primary-key-to-1). And it still doesn't work.
I looked into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534388/django-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint) and realized maybe my probmlem is the same and maybe DRF is creating two new instances which is why I get the error. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why is pk int the fields list? Probably this is the problem, when you are creating a Package via API you are passing 1 as pk. Try to add pk to the property read_only_fields

```
read_only_fields = ('pk',)
```

So you don't need it when you create a Package via API.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: Probably it is necessary to check the save() method inside the Package Model.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you. there was two calls to super's save method.

Comment: It always happens :) Happy you solved it.